# mejorar velocidad de O(n^2) en for anidado para búsqueda de combinaciones

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estaba haciendo este problema que consiste en dadas unas entradas de un **arreglo de enteros y un numero n**.. encontrar todos los **pares de elementos** en el arreglo que **sumados sean iguales a n** y de existir varios pares elegir el par **mas cercano a la izquierda**... Ej:

> arr=[10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], n=10
>
> ```
>        ^--------^ [5,5] 5+5=10
>            ^--^   [3,7] 3+7=10 *mas cercano a la izquierda
> ```
>
> reultado = [3,7]

Este es uno de los ejemplos mas simples de usos de for anidado para probar todas las combinaciones de dos elementos en un arreglo(busqueda binaria)...
Esta es mi solución...

```js
var sum_pairs = function (ints, s) {
    let min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
    let resp = []
    for (let i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++)
        for (let j = i + 1; j < ints.length; j++)
            if ((ints[i] + ints[j] == s) && (j < min)) {
                resp.push([ints[i], ints[j]]), min = j;
            }
    return (resp.length == 1) ? resp[0] : (resp.length > 1) ? resp[resp.length - 1] : undefined
}


console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));
console.log(sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));
```

recorre el arreglo buscando todas las combinaciones del primer numero, si suman **n** y su segundo numero(j) esta mas a la izquierda del min  lo añade al arreglo `resp[]`... si encuentra una sola solución retorna `resp[]` sino y existen varios pares regresa el ultimo elemento en `resp[]`(que por ende estaba mas a la izquierda)... sino encuentra ningún par regresa **undefined**... hace lo que pide el problema y era mas compleja, la fui resumiendo porque no pasaba los test de velocidad..  pero aun es O(n^2)... me gustaría saber como mejorar su complejidad o como hacer una solución mas rápida para este tipo de problemas...

Comment: ¿Tiene o no que devolver todos los pares encontrados? Por que si al final solo hay que elegir 1... apenas exista un par a distancia 1 podrías dejar de controlar.

Comment: tienes razon @Marcos es un solo par.. asi se pueden eliminar varios casos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El truco de solo usar una iteracion, es saber los valores que existían anteriormente en este caso te recomiendo [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

En este ejemplo lo usaremos para guardar en su ***key*** el valor del arreglo y el ***value*** la posicion del mismo.

Una vez teniendo esto claro , cuando iteremos solo debemos calcular la diferencia  **s** con respecto al numero que se esta consultadon y validar si este valor existe en el Map

```
let numeroFaltante = s - ints[i];   
numeroEncontrado = numbers.get(numeroFaltante);
```

Todo el codigo a continuacion:

```js
var sum_pairs = function (ints, s) {
    const numbers = new Map();
    numbers.set(ints[0],0);
    const combinacion = {
      numeros: [],
      diferencia: 99
    };
    
    for (let i = 1; i < ints.length ; i++){

      let numeroFaltante = s - ints[i];
      numeroEncontrado = numbers.get(numeroFaltante);
   
      if(numeroEncontrado >= 0){
        let diferencia = i - numeroEncontrado;
        if (combinacion.diferencia > diferencia){
          combinacion.numeros = [numeroFaltante , ints[i]];
          combinacion.diferencia = diferencia;
        
        }
      }
      numbers.set(ints[i],i)
    }
    return combinacion.numeros;
}


console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10));
console.log(sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4], 6));
console.log(sum_pairs([4,-2,3,3,4] , 8));
console.log(sum_pairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta JackNavaRow... sin embargo probando para algunos casos como a= [4,-2,3,3,4] n=8;  f() me regresa []; igual para a= [1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15] n= 8 f() regresa []; es mas rapida estoy averiguando ahora porque sucede esto

Comment: ups un error, cuando la posicion es cero(0) y haces if(numeroEncontrado) esto es falso, ya cambie la condicion

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta esta solucion es mas rapida.... y pasa los test

Comment: otra cosa cuando el par mas a la izquierda es el mismo numero, [1,1] n=2 la funcion no encontrara el par prueba para a=[1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 15] n=2

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema de la primera solucion con (for anidado); ocurre cuando se deben buscar los pares en un arreglo muy grande... pues de esta forma estamos buscando todas las combinaciones del primer elemento, luego las del segundo elemento, tercer elemento... y no puedes parar al encontrar el primer par, pues existe la otra condicion de que debes regresar el par mas cercano a la izquierda... ahi falla el test de velocidad. Una forma bastante sencilla es utilizar la tecnica de la respuesta anterior de jacknavarow junto con memoisation..

```js
let sum_pairsUp = (a, n) => {
    let memoisation = {}
    for (x of a) {
        if (memoisation[n - x])
            return [n - x, x]
        else
            memoisation[x] = 1
    }
}

console.log(sum_pairsUp([12, 4, 1,2,34,12,2,6,2,8,36, 7, 3, 15], 10));
console.log(sum_pairsUp([1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 15], 2)); //para repetidos
console.log(sum_pairsUp([1, 4, 1, 7, 3, 15], 25));
```